# Remove special characters from part of JSON String

Tags: java, json, java-8

How can I extract a part of the a JSON string and format it.
I'm using `ObjectMapper(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)` to extract data and format it. This is the sample payload and I want to remove the special characters from 'comments' and send it back. I extracted the comment and removed the special characters.

How can I extract all the text upto  `"recevied": "success"` into a string? then I can append like string1+ comment+ timestamp +notification and send it back.
Is there any way we can filter and format the comment in Java8 stream?

```
{
    "event": "myevent",
    "type": "Mytype",
    "payload": {
        "customer": {
            "cutype": "RETAIL",
            "customer_payload": {
                "customer_details": {
                    "payment": {
                        "type": "card",
                        "location": "some_location"
                    },
                    "payment2": {
                        "type": "card",
                        "location": "some_location"
                    },
                    "someotherinfo": {
                        "type": "card",
                        "location": "some_location"
                    },
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "recevied": "success",
                    "comments": "Test comment's and some more comment's"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "timestamp": "2022-01-09T18:44:17.571Z",
    "notification": "YES"
}
```

I used the `lastIndexOf` and `IndexOf` method and I want to use JSON objectmapper or java8 stream API.

Comment: "I tried to using..." Please [edit] your question to show the code you tried. Then show the output when you run your code, including any errors. And explain what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Is it that you want to add some fields as siblings to the `received` field? The better way to "manipulate" json would be to deserialize the json into an object, add the data you want, then serialize it back to json.

Comment: Sorry, what I want to do is remove the special characters from the comments like ",',:, and send it back. No other changes in the payload. or If I can extract upto recevied: success into a single string and I can append the rest.

Comment: I recommend that you do as Bohemian mentioned: deserialize the JSON into an object (maybe a `Map`) manipulate the data structure, then serialize it back to JSON. You will find this much easier than trying to manipulate the string directly.

Comment: Treating JSON or XML as text usually is a bad practice. Treat it as JSON using a JSON parser, modify the JSON objects, then write again using a JSON parser. That is what others are recommending.

Comment: @jen in your comment, you say *what I want to do is remove the special characters from the comments like ",',:, and send it back*, and if the task is to clean the string, then the json can be treated as a plain string, but in your question you say *I can append like string1+ comment+ timestamp +notification and send it back*. Which is it? Please edit your question to clarify which one the actual task is, or if it's both etc. Please add some simple (don't need the *whole* json - just enough to demonstrate edge cases) examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove unwanted characters from `"comments"` fields (as per chars `"':` listed in the comment above) in one line:

```java
json = Pattern.compile("\"comments\"\\s*:\\s*\")((\\\\\"|[^\"])+)")
  .matcher(json)
  .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1) + mr.group(2).replaceAll("\\\\?[\"':]", ""));
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/hSfPRB).

This also handles (shown in demo) deleting quotes `\"` in comments, which are *two* characters because they're escaped.

It also works with flexible whitespace between the field name and field value, so `"comments":"something"` and  and `"comments" :   "something"` etc all work, and this code preserves it too.

This makes use of Matcher's [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst(java.util.function.Function)), that streams the matches and accepts a function that can do the task of cleaning `comments` fields' values of unwanted characters.

The regex breakdown is of the Pattern is:

- `(\"comments\"\\s*:\\s*\")` means `"comments", zero or more whitespace, a colon, zero or more whitespace. Captured as group 1 (via the brackets)
- `((\\\\\"|[^\"])+)` means one or more or either `\"` *OR* anything not a quote. Captured as group 2 (via the brackets). ie the entire value of a `comment` field